# Error: Could not find versioned identity endpoints when attempting to authenticate

Tags: virtual-machine, openstack, ubuntu-20.04, devstack

I am trying to set-up a new stack with the below commands in python 3.9.15 and Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. I created a stack user and cloned devstack using 'git clone [https://opendev.org/openstack/devstack'](https://opendev.org/openstack/devstack%27) and checkout yoga series and granted all permisssion to user with help of chmod 755. Creating the local.conf file using below configuration.

```
   vi local.conf

   [[local|localrc]]

   GIT_BASE=${GIT_BASE:-https://git.openstack.org}

   ADMIN_PASSWORD=xxxx
   DATABASE_PASSWORD=xxxxx
   RABBIT_PASSWORD=xxxxx
   SERVICE_PASSWORD=xxxx
   HOST_IP=10.197.38.22x
   #all the parameters below are optional
   USE_SCREEN=TRUE

   VERBOSE=True
   LOG_COLOR=True

   NOVA_REPO=$GIT_BASE/openstack/nova.git
   NOVA_BRANCH=stable/yoga

   NEUTRON_REPO=$GIT_BASE/openstack/neutron.git
   NEUTRON_BRANCH=stable/yoga

   HORIZON_REPO=$GIT_BASE/openstack/horizon.git
   HORIZON_BRANCH=stable/yoga

   GLANCE_REPO=$GIT_BASE/openstack/glance.git
   GLANCE_BRANCH=stable/yoga

   ./stack.sh
```

while running last command './stack.sh' I am getting error :

```
  Failed to discover available identity versions when contacting           http://10.197.38.224/identity. Attempting to parse version from URL.
  Could not find versioned identity endpoints when attempting to authenticate. Please check      that your auth_url is correct. Internal Server Error (HTTP 500)
  ++functions-common:oscwrap:2491 return 1
  +lib/keystone:create_keystone_accounts:310 admin_project=
  +lib/keystone:create_keystone_accounts:1 exit_trap
  +./stack.sh:exit_trap:521 local r=1
  ++./stack.sh:exit_trap:522 jobs -p
  +./stack.sh:exit_trap:522 jobs=80759
  +./stack.sh:exit_trap:525 [[ -n 80759 ]]
  +./stack.sh:exit_trap:525 [[ -n '' ]]
  +./stack.sh:exit_trap:531 '[' -f /tmp/tmp.d7oMMx7MH3 ']'
  +./stack.sh:exit_trap:532 rm /tmp/tmp.d7oMMx7MH3
  +./stack.sh:exit_trap:536 kill_spinner
  +./stack.sh:kill_spinner:431 '[' '!' -z '' ']'
  +./stack.sh:exit_trap:538 [[ 1 -ne 0 ]]
  +./stack.sh:exit_trap:539 echo 'Error on exit'
  Error on exit
  +./stack.sh:exit_trap:541 type -p generate-subunit
  +./stack.sh:exit_trap:542 generate-subunit 1668766307 716 fail
  +./stack.sh:exit_trap:544 [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
  +./stack.sh:exit_trap:547 /usr/bin/python3.9 /opt/stack/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d     /opt/stack/logs
 World dumping... see /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2022-11-18-102343.txt for details
 +./stack.sh:exit_trap:556 exit 1
```

Any help would be appreciated

I am trying to deploy devstack machine using python version 3.9.15 and ubuntu 20.04.4

Proxy information:

```
export HTTP_PROXY="IP_ADDRESS:80"     
export HTTPS_PROXY="IP_ADDRESS:80"
export http_proxy="IP_ADDRESS:80"     
export https_proxy="IP_ADDRESS:80"     
export NO_PROXY="127.0.0.1,IP_ADDRESS"
export no_proxy="127.0.0.1,IP_ADDRESS"
```

Comment: Is apache running?

Comment: yes, it is Also I restarted apache using - sudo systemctl restart apache2.service and after that, I am getting - 
/opt/stack/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
World dumping... see /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2022-11-21-062703.txt for details
ovs-vsctl: unix:/var/run/openvswitch/db.sock: database connection failed (No such file or directory)
ovs-vsctl: unix:/var/run/openvswitch/db.sock: database connection failed (No such file or directory)
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:556                  exit 1

Comment: Please add further output to your question as they can get lost in the comments. I'm not really familiar with devstack, but are neutron and openvswitch actually installed?

Comment: I am following the link - https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/ to install the basic setup in ubuntu 20.04 and python version 3.9. It throws the error -
Failed to discover available identity versions when contacting http://10.197.38.233/identity. Attempting to parse version from URL.
Could not find versioned identity endpoints when attempting to authenticate. Please check that your auth_url is correct. Internal Server Error (HTTP 500)

Comment: Usually, keystone listens to a specific port (5000 or in older version 35357), is apache configured to listen to that port? You can start with `lsof -Pi | grep -E "5000|35357"` to see if any of those ports is open.

Comment: No, these are not open. 
stack@test:~/devstack$ lsof -Pi | grep -E "5000|35357"
stack@test:~/devstack$

Comment: I tried to setup a devstack vm but it fails, so I can't reproduce at the moment. But I see the configs, there are no ports defined as I mentioned. So forget that part. I'll try to setup my vm and get back to this thread if you won't fix it until then.

Comment: Can you try following the above steps and see if you are getting the same error?

Comment: Is your VM behind a proxy? I saw a similar message when I forgot to set the correct `no_proxy` variable. With correct proxy settings my stack.sh command worked fine. This is my version: `DevStack Version: 2023.1
Change: 2795e8215da782e9d485c3ba5df1bd0a622658a5 Merge "Switch devstack nodeset to Ubuntu 22.04 (jammy)" 2022-11-19 22:03:55 +0000
OS Version: Ubuntu 20.04 focal`

Comment: check the output of `curl -v http://10.197.38.224/identity` and add it to your question, remove all sensitive data.

Comment: stack@test:~/devstack$ curl -v http://10.197.38.23x/identity
*   Trying 10.197.38.23x:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 10.197.38.23x (10.197.38.23x) port 80 (#0)
> GET /identity HTTP/1.1
> Host: 10.197.38.23x
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Date: Tue, 22 Nov 2022 13:10:01 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Connection: close
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
* Closing connection 0
Internal Server Error

Comment: How did you remove no_proxy variable? Can you share link or commands to do so?

Comment: Don't add command line output as a comment, they will get lost, add them to your question (edit) with code tags.

Answer (score 0):

According to your output it tries to reach your identity endpoint through a proxy. You have to set the correct proxy variables, for example this is my `/etc/environment` file:

```
export HTTP_PROXY="192.X.X.X:<PORT>"
export HTTPS_PROXY="192.X.X.X:<PORT>"
export http_proxy="192.X.X.X:<PORT>"
export https_proxy="192.X.X.X:<PORT>"
export NO_PROXY="127.0.0.1,<IP_ADDRESS>"
export no_proxy="127.0.0.1,<IP_ADDRESS>"
```

After logging out and back in the new environment variables are applied, you can check with `echo $http_proxy`. After having the correct proxy settings my deployment worked without an issue.

Comment: I tried this by replacing my machine's IP_ADDRESS but I am getting the error - 'Unsupported proxy configured:'

Comment: Please add the proxy information to your question, maybe it's a syntax error? I hope you didn't add the "<>" signs because those are just to indicate a place holder.

Comment: I have added Proxy information from /etc/environment in question, please do check and respond

Comment: And after adding the proxy information, did you log out and back in again? If you run the `curl -v` command again, does it still try to connect to the proxy or is it contacting the devstack server directly now? And are you sure that your proxy is serving via port 80? That sounds strange...